# Resolving `.local` name (mDNS only)

Tags: linux, dns, mdns

I have a home network set up using mDNS, containing assorted systems (including an always-on Raspberry Pi). My machines are running avahi daemons, so the current situation is:

- everybody on the network can resolve `host.local` names.

What I want in addition:

- the machines that I administrate can also resolve `host` to the same address as `host.local`.

I could think of three ways to do that:

1. Put `search local` in `/etc/resolv.conf`: [this is not honored by mDNS](http://0pointer.de/lennart/projects/nss-mdns/) as it was supposedly “causing problems”. I could recompile with the `--enable-search-domains` options on all my machines.
2. Write static `/etc/hosts` files in all network machines. This is what I currently do. However, it makes configuration distributed, which I want to avoid (these files *do* eventually go out-of-sync).
3. Set up a DNS server on the network. However, the router provided with the Internet access does not do DNS (this is almost a good reason to change for another company), so I would need to set it up on the Raspberry. This also poses the problem of a distributed configuration: the static DNS info on the Raspberry would eventually go out of sync with the mDNS information, so that `host` and `host.local` could confusingly point to two different IP addresses...

So, my question is:

- what are the “problems” posed by the `--enable-search-domains` option? (The only one I see is that it enables anyone on the LAN to set up an unqualified host name, but 1. I don't use unqualified host names apart from those I already control, and 2. LAN access is already restricted to trusted peers anyway).
- did I miss any other fourth option? (such as, setup a DNS server + a crontab periodically feeding it with some output of an `avahi-browse` command?)

Comment: This is an out-of-topic comment, I suspect you misunderstood the question. The `.local` domain works fine, I want to make it the default domain. I edited for clarity.

Comment: This question is not bizarre at all.  In fact, out of all the googling I've done about this issue, and all the StackOverflow/AskUbuntu/SuperUser questions I've found that are related to this issue, this question is the **only one** that accurately describes the problem, potential solutions, and the issues with those solutions.  I have been searching for answers to the question of why `--enable-search-domains` is not enabled by default, why it was disabled in the first place, but I haven't found any yet.

Comment: Now that `--enable-search-domains` has been removed as a feature, are there other options?

Answer (score 5):

The reason mdns doesn't append .local or search domains is because there is no NXDOMAIN or similar concept in mdns.

So if mdns fails to find a resolution in any caches, it must send a multicast query and wait to see if anything responds. This timeout is lengthy enough for "causing problems".

The following doesn't answer the question, but is speculative of possible implementations to resolve some of the issues.

What I would wish for is to explicitly append .local to hostnames without any dots at the end of the nss chain. E.G.

hosts: files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns_append

Perhaps it would also be possible to specify a "cache only" mdns resolution. Perhaps with an nsswitch like this

hosts: files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] mdns_append_cacheonly dns mdns_append

I envision mdns_append trying both with and without .local appended.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the option is 'not recommended' because it's nearly useless in practice: almost all other mDNS implementations use the `.local` domain *only*, so trying to do lookups for whatever domain you happened to obtain from DHCP would only introduce additional delays most of the time. There are also [security issues](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6762#section-13) mentioned in the actual mDNS spec.

Instead, nss-mdns could be patched to *specifically* append `.local` to dotless names before trying to look them up, instead of using the resolv.conf domains.

Comment: The `search` directive in `resolv.conf` specifically gives the list of domains to consider; if you say `search local` it would just append `.local`, not whatevery ou happen to get from DHCP.

Comment: That doesn't work, @DanielH. Only the `dns` nss resolver reads resolv.conf. The `mdns*` resolvers do not. This is not well-documented, though.

Comment: @enigmaticPhysicist Yeah I was wrong.  The RFC directly says implementations should do what I said, but you are correct that neither common implementation on Linux actually does.  I usually donʼt go in for systemd hate but in this case the guy behind `systemd-resolved` is the same one behind `avahi` and doesnʼt even provide an option to follow the spec here in either program.